# Figures on the same page as text using elsarticle

Tags: floats, elsarticle, figure-placement

I can not find a solution to get my figures and text on the same page. The figures go always on the next page and do not float in the text. Happy, if anyone could help me!
I know there is already a similar topic on stack exchange, which could not solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins} % used to allow \floatbarrier
\usepackage{stfloats, cuted, caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}


\title{figures in elsarticle }

\author{Mira }
\address{University of }

\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction}

\blindtext
\blindtext
 
\section{Results}

\subsection{subsection 1}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[tb]
\centering    
\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{Figure1.jpg}
    \caption{\textbf{Effect of Conazoles on rosette formation}\\
  } 
\end{figure*}

\blindtext

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\blindtext
 \begin{figure*}[ht]
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Figure2.JPG}
\caption{\textbf{Prescreen of conazoles}\\}
\end{figure*}

\section{Discussion}
\blindtext

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{literatur.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Someone will edit your question as your code isn't in a code block, if you paste your code into the question and then highlight it and click `{}` on the menu it will format as code

Comment: Thanks! its my first post :D

Comment: LaTeX's build-in twocolumn mode does not support *here* placed figures spanning both columns. Only figures, which fit into one column can be placed *here*. So all `\begin{figure*}…\end{figure*}` will be moved at least to the start of the next page. If you don't want to span the figure to both columns, use `\begin{figure}…\end{figure}` (without star). BTW: You should not add `\\ ` at the end of the caption text (and usually not use `\textbf` to make all caption texts bold).

Comment: why do you have  `\\ ` at the end of captions? They must surely generate warnings?  `figure*` does not have `h` so `\begin{figure*}[ht]`  is `\begin{figure*}[t]` so the only effect is to remove `p` and make it more  likely the figure goes to the end. Just use `\begin{figure*}`.  It will always come, at earliest, on the next page, so just place it earlier in the source file if it s placed too late.